# jQuery stopPropagation for click on android

Tags: android, jquery, stoppropagation

I have a "hiddeable" element, it hides when the user click on it, except when the user click in an input text field, the script is very simple:

```
$('#main_table #sidebar .mini_hid').click(function(){
    $('#main_table #sidebar').removeClass('show');
});
$('#main_table #sidebar .mini_hid input[type="text"]').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

To hide the element I remove the "show" class, and to avoid to trigger it clicking the text field I use a stopPropagation.

This works fine on Computers and Mac, but in Android devices stopPropagation is not working, so when an user clicks on the text field the whole element hides.

I need the stopPropagation() works to avoid hidding its container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved this issue changing the `click` event for `mouseup`.

```
$('#main_table #sidebar .mini_hid').mouseup(function(){
    $('#main_table #sidebar').removeClass('show');
});
$('#main_table #sidebar .mini_hid input[type="text"]').mouseup(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

This is not really a full solution but a workaround.